# Es6 class variables

Tags: ecmascript-6

I've made this ES6 class, and I'm trying to use the variables I defined in the constructor, but when I console.log `this.customerTz` it returns `undefined`.

I've also tried to put variables at the top of the class, but it doesn't seem to work.
Is it possible to have variables?

```
class DateTimeConverter {
constructor() {
    this.format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
    this.customerTz = 'Europe/Oslo';
}

static convertToUtc(date) {
    console.log(this.customerTz);
    // Set customer timezone
    date = moment.tz(date, this.customerTz);

    // Convert to UTC
    date = date.clone().tz('UTC');

    // Set format to something PHP thinks is valid
    date = date.format(this.format);

    return date;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you do not want a `class` at all, as there is no reason to instantiate this constructor. Instead, use a plain object literal for your module:

```
const DateTimeConverter = {
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    customerTz: 'Europe/Oslo',
    convertToUtc(date) {
        console.log(this.customerTz);
        // Set customer timezone
        date = moment.tz(date, this.customerTz);

        // Convert to UTC
        date = date.clone().tz('UTC');

        // Set format to something PHP thinks is valid
        date = date.format(this.format);

        return date;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`convertToUtc` is a static method and it can't access any property on instance. Instead you can modify the code like below

```js
class DateTimeConverter {
    
    static convertToUtc(date) {
        console.log(DateTimeConverter.customerTz); // Static property
        
        // Set customer timezone
        date = moment.tz(date, DateTimeConverter.customerTz);
    
        // Convert to UTC
        date = date.clone().tz('UTC');
    
        // Set format to something PHP thinks is valid
        date = date.format(DateTimeConverter.format);
    
        return date;
    }
}

DateTimeConverter.format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
DateTimeConverter.customerTz = 'Europe/Oslo';


console.log(DateTimeConverter.convertToUtc(new Date()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `convertToUtc` is a static method, you have no instance `this` of the DateTimeConverter class when you are calling convertToUtc method. You could make `convertToUtc` to not be a static method and then call it on an instance of the DateTimeConverter class.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `convertToUtc` is static. Static functions are associated with the class itself and not instances of the class. The constructor is not called because you don't create an instance. so `this.customerTz` will not be defined inside the function. take out the `static`

```
class DateTimeConverter {
  constructor() {
   this.format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
   this.customerTz = 'Europe/Oslo';
  }

  convertToUtc(date) {
   console.log(this.customerTz);

   date = moment.tz(date, this.customerTz);

   // Convert to UTC
   date = date.clone().tz('UTC');

   // Set format to something PHP thinks is valid
   date = date.format(this.format);

   return date;
  }
}
```